# Rendering something on my React (jsx) front end by implementing logic in a liquid section for the Shopify Customizer

Tags: reactjs, jsx, shopify, liquid

I am new to React and don't really have knowledge of liquid but I'm learning as I go. I have been reading documentation for days trying to figure out how to do this. My task is to create a checkbox in my Shopify store customizer (which I've done) and based on if that box is true (checked) or false (unchecked), I want to render a span in my React jsx in *different *file. How can I do this? If this box is checked, make sure that the code in my jsx is rendered?

Here is an example of what my section code looks like in the liquid file :

```
window.enableText = {{ section.settings.enable_this_text | json }}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Thing",
  "tag": "section",
  "max_blocks": 3,
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_this_text",
      "label": "Enable Text",
      "default": false
    },
```

And then I have a different file that contains React where I want to render this span only if this liquid checkbox is checked/true:

`{checkForState && <span className="test-message">Test Message works!</span>}`

When I search for this solution, it's mostly tutorials about how to render something in the same liquid file but I don't necessarily want to do this. I already have what I want to render created in my jsx file, I just want to base that off of this checkbox being selected in the customizer.